# Compile error when comparing class types: non comparable type

Tags: java

There is the following code:

```java
    class A {}

    class B extends A {}

    @Test
    public void test4() {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        Class<? extends A> aClass = a.getClass();
        Class<? extends B> bClass = b.getClass();

        System.out.println(aClass == bClass);// #1 false

        System.out.println(aClass == A.class);// #2 true
        System.out.println(aClass == B.class);// #3 false

        System.out.println(bClass == A.class);// #4 error:java: non comparable type: java.lang.Class<capture#1, ? extends Test.B> and java.lang.Class<Test.A>
        System.out.println(bClass == B.class);// #5 true
    }
```

As shown above, I am very confused about this error. Because in my opinion, a.getClass() and A.class are the same object, and the values of these two variables are indeed the same when I debug. Then I think #3 and #4 are equivalent, there should be no error. I feel like it might be some cause of type erasure, but I don't know much about it.

Does anyone know what could be the reason for this?

Comment: for sure `a.getClass()` is the same instance as `A.class`,  but `A` does not extend `B` - `bClass` is declared as being `Class<? extends B>`  but `A.class` returns a `Class<A>` - `Class<A>` can never be assigned to a `Class<? extends B>` variable, so this comparison does not make sense - it will always be `false`

Comment: #3 and #4 are not equivalent.  For #3, it is entirely possible that, at runtime, `a` could reference an instance of `B`, so it is perfectly possible for #3 to be `true`.  The same is NOT true for #4 since it is not possible for variable `b` to reference an instance of A itself.  MAYBE it is this impossibility that the compiler is alerting you to, but will have to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit like wondering why you can write

```
String s = "hi";
Integer i = 42;
Object so = s;
Object io = i;

System.out.println(so == io); // compiles, prints false
System.out.println(s == i); // compilation error: String and Integer are incomparable types
```

in spite of `so` and `s` referring to the same object. Well, it's because the compiler is checking types, not objects. It's obvious nonsense to compare a `String` and `Integer` with `==`. It's less obvious nonsense to compare two `Object` with `==`.

So let's look at the types:

```
aClass == B.class
```

asks whether some subclass of `A` is in fact `B`. Since `B` is a subclass of `A`, that's quite possible. For instance, the following program will print true:

```
A a = new B();
Class<? extends A> aClass = a.getClass();
System.out.println(aClass == B.class);
```

(the ability to put a `B` into a variable declared with type `A` is precisely why `getClass()` returns `Class<? extends A>` rather than `Class<A>`)

On the other hand

```
bClass == A.class
```

doesn't make sense. It asks whether `bClass`, which is some subclass of `B`, is `A`. It that were true, `A` would be subclass of `B`, which is declared to be a subclass of `A`, so `A` and `B` would be subclasses of each other! That's impossible!